# Finding current ix

Tags: voltage, current

[image]

We need to find the current ix where Gm = 0.2 S. What I've done so far if created two equations using node voltage.

Eq. 1 : Vx/330 - 440ix/330 -ix +gmVx = 0

Eq. 2 : 50Vx/1200 + 50ix - 50gmVx + Vx = 5.6

Matrix (Ax=B) looks like this:

```
A = (1/330)+.2            (-440/330) - 1 

    (1/24)-50(.2)+1       50

x = Vx
    ix

B = 0
    5.6
```

Did I do this correctly? If not, what should I do?

Comment: Your Eq 2 looks like a mesh equation, not a node equation. You can probably get a right answer that way, but it would be more clear if you just write two node equations instead of mixing up node and mesh analysis.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thank you! I'll try and solve it now and I'll let you know what I get!

Comment: The top node (where the ix arrow is) of the 440 Ohm resistor will also have some voltage. You can name that V_y. Since you know gm, you'll be solving for Vx and Vy, knowing that Vy = ix*440.

Comment: @ThePhoton I tried using the equations I came up and then put them into Ax = B form... but I got a negative i which can't be right. Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: Please edit the question to give your new equations.

Comment: @ThePhoton Just updated it

Comment: Node equations should all be in terms of node voltages. If you want to solve with the nodal method, just write the usual nodal equations and then find the desired current in terms of the voltages. Obviously you can jump a few steps ahead in your mind, but if you want it to be clear to others what you're doing, just take it step by step.

Comment: Try this for your first equation: \$ \frac{V_X}{50 \: \Omega} + \frac{V_X}{330 \: \Omega} + \frac{V_X}{1.2 \: \textrm{k}\Omega} = \frac{5.6 \: \textrm{V}}{50 \: \Omega} + \frac{V_Y}{330 \: \Omega} \$. I've used \$V_Y\$ for the other node at the top right of your schematic.

Comment: @jonk What would my second equation be then?

Comment: It would of course be: \$\frac{V_Y}{330\:\Omega}+\frac{V_Y}{440\:\Omega} = \frac{V_X}{330\:\Omega} + g_m\cdot V_x\$. Solve for \$V_Y\$ and you can figure out the current you want. When you look at a node, put the currents that are "spilling outward" on the left side of the equation. Then put the currents that are "spilling inward" on the right side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May as well write it out.

Writing outward spilling currents on the left, inward spilling currents on the right, I get:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_X}{50\:\Omega}+\frac{V_X}{330\:\Omega}+\frac{V_X}{1.2\:\textrm{k}\Omega}&=\frac{5.6\:\textrm{V}}{50\:\Omega}+\frac{V_Y}{330\:\Omega}\\\\
\frac{V_Y}{330\:\Omega}+\frac{V_Y}{440\:\Omega}&=\frac{V_X}{330\:\Omega}+g_m\cdot V_X\\\\&=V_X\cdot\left(g_m+\frac{1}{330\:\Omega}\right)\\\\
&\therefore\\\\
\left(\frac{1}{50\:\Omega}+\frac{1}{330\:\Omega}+\frac{1}{1.2\:\textrm{k}\Omega}\right)\cdot V_X-\frac{1}{330\:\Omega}\cdot V_Y&=\frac{5.6\:\textrm{V}}{50\:\Omega}\\\\
-\left(g_m+\frac{1}{330\:\Omega}\right)\cdot V_X+\left(\frac{1}{330\:\Omega}+\frac{1}{440\:\Omega}\right)\cdot V_Y&=0\:\textrm{A}
\end{align*}$$

Just solve the above matrix.

Comment: So i put it into matrix form and got Vy = 37.65. Assuming I got the voltage right, would I just use i = V/r = 37.65/440 = .084 A?

Comment: @T.Bui Those aren't the solving values I get. Both \$V_X\$ and \$V_Y\$ should be negative, to begin with.

Comment: Oh sorry dropped a minus sign. I got Vx = -1.23 and Vy= -47.115

Comment: @T.Bui Yeah. That looks better. I get \$V_X\approx -1.21536\:\textrm{V}\$ and \$V_Y\approx -46.531\:\textrm{V}\$.

Comment: @T.Bui So, yes. The answer for \$i_x\$ is either a negative value, or else it should be \$\approx 106\:\textrm{mA}\$ but with the arrow pointed in the opposite direction.

Comment: @T.Bui Yes. That's about right.